# How to pass NSURLCredential to NSURLSession?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlcredential

I'm a little confused by this. I have this method.

```
-(BOOL)verifyAuth: (NSString*)username forPassword:(NSString*)password
{
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLCredential *creds = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

    [session dataTaskWithURL:MALAuthVerifyURL completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) 
    {

         NSLog(@"%@",data);
    }];
    return YES;
}
```

How do I pass the credentials to the NSURLSession object? Apple's docs say this:

"After you’ve created the NSURLCredential object:

For NSURLSession, pass the object to the authentication challenge’s sender using the provided completion handler block."

But i'm not sure what this actually means. I can't find any examples of this usage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009507-SW1

HTTP basic authentication (NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic) requires a user name and password. Prompt the user for the necessary information and create an NSURLCredential object with credentialWithUser:password:persistence:.

After you’ve created the NSURLCredential object:

- For NSURLSession, pass the object to the authentication challenge’s sender using the provided completion handler block.
- For NSURLConnection and NSURLDownload, pass the object to the authentication challenge’s sender with useCredential:forAuthenticationChallenge:.

Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement another delegate method, `-URLSession:task:didReceiveChallenge:challenge:completionHandler:`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What about basic HTTP authorization where you're not waiting for a challenge from the server, but passing the username:password in with every request?

Comment: @Joseph My guess would be: create your Session based on your own NSURLSessionConfiguration, which has a URLCredentialStorage property you can set. Set that up with a Credential/Protection Space with NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic and I'd imagine it would use that instead issuing the challenge callback. This isn't something I've tried yet, though...